# GatsbyJS: is it possible to query inside a component created in the layouts folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, gatsby

I've created a component inside my layouts folder, and have tried to use a query to grab information from contentful. My code is pretty identical to that which I have used inside another working component, inside the pages folder. However, that in the layouts folder isn't working; this.props.data console logs as undefined.

Is there some special way to query when it comes to components in the layouts folder? Is there something I'm missing here? I've read both that I can and cannot query inside the layouts folder in GatsbyJS...

here is the code for my component inside the layouts folder:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {  
      return (
          my component code
  }

  export const headerQuery = graphql`
    query headerQuery {
        allContentfulBlogPost {
            edges {
                node {
                    postTitle
                    postDate
                }
            }
            totalCount
        }
    }
`
```

Comment: There's nothing special about queries for layout components. How are you testing if the query is running or now?

Comment: Also you should only have one layout component at layouts/index.js — this looks like a regular component. Move this into a file at src/components/header.js and then move the query into layouts/index.js and then import the Header component there and then pass the data from the query to the Header.

Comment: i had been using console.log to check out whether i got a data object inside the render function. I followed your instructions and everything is working fine now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was covered in the comments.

No.

Data is delivered to components in Gatsby only via queries in pages or layouts. This single point of entry allows Gatsby to compile your data to static JSON files on disk, and to pre-fetch data, etc.